# Which one should I use ("suggesting" or "to suggest") in the example provided?

Tags: verbs, gerunds

> **I can’t find anything suggesting** that one cannot take out principle from Roth IRA account for education or housing purchases. Nor it’s indicated that money are doled out in a form of a loan.

Part in bold is under question. However, I would also appreciate your pointing out other errors too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'To suggest' is more common, though both make sense.

As for other errors, it should perhaps be 'take out *the* principle from *the* Roth IRA account'.

And it should definitely be 'Nor is it', not 'nor it's'. 'It's' is a contraction of 'it is', not 'is it'. Also, it should be 'money is' not 'money are' (money is collective/singular), and it should be 'in *the* form' not 'a form'.

Altogether:

> I can't find anything to suggest that one cannot take out the principle from the Roth IRA account for education or housing purchases. Nor is it indicated that money is doled out in the form of a loan.

Comment: why "the" before Roth IRA account?

Comment: and why the before "form" since i am NOT talking about the specific form?

Comment: 'why "the" before Roth IRA account?' - because you are talking about a specific account. If you were talking more generally you would leave it out. - 'take out the principle from savings accounts.'

Answer (score 2):

> I can’t find anything **that** suggests...

Comment: This is pretty common too.

Comment: but then you'll have *that...that*, which is not too nice.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it should be *principal*, not *principle*. The former refers, among other things, to the original amount deposited (as opposed to interest, etc.), which is what's being referred to here.